# The roll of IMU in robot pose estimation

Tags: ros, imu, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to ask whats the roll of IMU in the lokalisation . I mean why and how to use IMU in the motion estimation with EKF or AMCL (particle filter)

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49353/the-roll-of-imu-in-robot-pose-estimation/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An IMU is one of many sensors which can be used to estimate robot motion through integration at high data frequency (dead reckoning) while external pose corrections are not available (via GPS, landmarks, etc).

Specifically, if your IMU contains an accelerometer and a gyro you may use it to estimate linear displacement (by integrating accelerations twice in all three axes) and angular displacement (by integrating angular velocities once in all three axes).

As an added bonus, if your IMU also contains a magnetometer, you may use it to correct the pose estimate obtained by the process mentioned earlier, if you make some considerations about your own acceleration and the local gravitational and magnetic fields.

The reason why you need external pose corrections is that these sensors contain errors that, when integrated, generate a drift in your estimate (i.e. your estimate eventually diverges because of random fluctuations around the mean). So external pose corrections, even if not always available, allow you to bound the pose uncertainty.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-11-29**:
thanks. Just one question. How to use it IMU with AMCL and also the imu data like angular velocity and linear acceleration. Any help?

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-11-30**:
I haven't used amcl before, but my guess is that you would have to publish the result of integrating the IMU data as if it were the odometry tf, considering /base_frame as the starting point and /odom_frame as the uncorrected estimate (http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl#Transforms)